# Perturbation of the self-dual harmonic $2$-forms

Tags: riemannian-geometry, 4-manifolds

Let $M$ be a closed oriented smooth $4$-manifold with $m=b^+_2(M)>0$. We set $\mathcal R$ to be the space of smooth metrics on $M$ and consider the following map $f:\mathcal R \to Gr(m,n)$ defined for any $g \in \mathcal R$,
$$
g \to [\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots, \alpha_m].
$$
Here, $\{\alpha_i\}$ is a basis of self-dual harmonic two-forms defined by $g$ and $n=b_2(M)$.

Can we prove the map $f$ is a submersion?

Comment: No, I don't think this is known, but see Donaldson and Kronheimer, 4.3.5. There are some results [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.16820) on surjectivity.